# How do I dynamically select a specific link with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to select a certain link and open a dialog box.

```
  $('#edit').click(function(e) {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var dialog_form = $('<div id="dialog-form">Loading form...</div>').dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      width: 520,
      modal: true,
      open: function() {
        return $(this).load(url + ' #content');
      },
      close: function() {
        $('#dialog-form').remove();
      }
    });
    dialog_form.dialog('open');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

On a page with multiple edit links

```
<a href="articles/edit/1" id="edit">edit</a>
<a href="articles/edit/2" id="edit">edit</a>
```

but the code only works when there is only one edit link.

How do I dynamically select the exact link I click on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ID` attributes need to be unique, that is invalid HTML. Browsers will return always the first occurrence.

You can use a classname instead.

```
<a href="articles/edit/1" class="edit">edit</a>
```

And, you will need to modify your selector to `.edit` to find elements by classname.

```
$('.edit').click(function(e) {
  ... 
});
```

As of HTML5, you can also make use of `data-*` attributes.

Comment: This has worked, thank you!  Do you know why what hohner suggested wasn't working? (using "on" instead of "click")

Comment: @DanielSunYang, what version of jQuery are you using? Anyways, that suggestion was groundless because `.click()` uses internally `.on()`. You may use `.on()` for event delegation which clearly isn't happening neither on your code nor his answer

Comment: Ah, you're right.  I was using someone's example application and it has "jquery v1.6.1".  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @DanielSunYang, you can use normally `.click()` because this shorthand should use the recommended way to bind event handlers with your current version. Although, upgrading jQuery is always recommended

Comment: Now I'm stuck with the dilemma of choosing from two correct answers D:, the holes I dig for myself...

Answer (score 2):

First of all, **do not use duplicate ID attributes** - they're supposed to be unique for each element in the DOM. If you want a selector, use classnames instead:

```
<a href="articles/edit/1" class="edit">edit</a>
<a href="articles/edit/2" class="edit">edit</a>
```

Secondly, use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `click()`:

```
$('.edit').on('click', function(e) {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var dialog_form = $('<div id="dialog-form">Loading form...</div>').dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      width: 520,
      modal: true,
      open: function() {
        return $(this).load(url + ' #content');
      },
      close: function() {
        $('#dialog-form').remove();
      }
    });
    dialog_form.dialog('open');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Comment: I beg to disagree but there's no advantage in using `.on()` instead of `.click()` there

Comment: I don't know why, but "on" doesn't work but 'click' seems to work with the id to class change you mentioned.

Comment: @DanielSunYang you need to be using on() because click() is becoming deprecated. Update your version of jQuery and you'll be able to use it.

Comment: @Alexander because in the future he'll most likely want to access events for dynamically added elements

Comment: @hohner, Can you provide a reference to the deprecation notice of `.click()`? I'm sorry but I think you are a bit confused

Comment: Hohner, you were right, too, I was just using an older version of jQuery. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Alexander sorry, I meant `live()`. But you're right - `click()` as of 1.7 serves as a shortcut for `.on('click')`. I just prefer to use `on()` so everything's covered if I require more dynamic functionality in the future

Comment: @hohner, please don't confuse event delegation with [normal] event binding. Because that syntax is not event delegation though and don't use `.live()` as of jQuery 1.7 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Two elements with the same id is invalid HTML. Use class instead.